# jQuery/Validation: form with invalidHandler is always submitted

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery (1.8.2) and the [Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) (1.10.0) to validate a form. My problem is that when setting a custom `invalidHandler`, my form is submitted even when there are errors.

### The long version

The form is quite long and has several fields that can be hidden from view (using `jQuery.toggle()`) to make the form easier to work with. Now, some of these fields are "optionally required", i.e. I only care about their content if a corresponding checkbox is checked. So I have validators looking similar to this:

```
emailInvitationTitle: {
     required: function() {
        return $("#emailInvitation_chk").prop("checked");
    }
},
emailInvitationBody: {
    required: function() {
        return $("#emailInvitation_chk").prop("checked");
    }
}
```

So far, so good. However, if any of these "maybe hidden, maybe required" fields are invalid on submit, I want to show the relevant hidden sections (with class "messageEditor"). So I have an `invalidHandler` like this:

```
invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
    // If either title or body is empty, make sure their parent div is visible
    if (!(validator.element("#emailInvitationTitle") 
            && validator.element("#emailInvitationBody"))) {
        $("#emailInvitationTitle").closest(".messageEditor").show();
    }
}
```

The issue is that it seems by defining this `invalidHandler`, my form is always submitted, regardless whether the validation succeeds or not. I dug around in `jquery.validate.js` and observed the following (at line 331 and onward):

```
    // http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/form
    form: function() {
        this.checkForm();
        $.extend(this.submitted, this.errorMap);
        this.invalid = $.extend({}, this.errorMap);
        if (!this.valid()) {
            $(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form", [this]);
        }
        this.showErrors();
        return this.valid();
    },
```

I won't pretend I understand even half of it. But when tracing through this, I noticed that `this.valid()` correctly returns `false` on the first call, which causes my `invalidHandler` to trigger. However, `return this.valid()` yields `true` immediately after. Somehow the trigger (?) clears the validator's `errorList` array, causing the invalid form to be submitted.

Is this a bug with the validate plugin, or jQuery itself (or something else)?

Any suggestions for a fix/workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question with the workaround I eventually came to use.

I hacked around this problem by modifying the `form` function in `jquery.validate.js`:

```
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/form
form: function() {
    this.checkForm();
    $.extend(this.submitted, this.errorMap);
    this.invalid = $.extend({}, this.errorMap);
    var errorListCopy = this.errorList.slice(); // hack, step 1
    if (!this.valid()) {
        $(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form", [this]);            
        this.errorList = errorListCopy.concat(this.errorList); // hack, step 2
    }
    this.showErrors();
    return this.valid();
},
```

Still doesn't quite feel like the right way to go about it, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same problem. This seems like a bug in the plugin. The way I worked around this is the following:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
  if ($(form).validate().numberOfInvalids() != 0) {
    return false;
  }
  form.submit();
},
```